# Fixed List is not updating with for loop - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a fixed list reservedGuest. After checking the condition in for loop I want to update the seats if the membership date has expired. The list is not updating. The code is as follows. PS. The List is filled through API on init().

```
class MyClubController extends GetxController {
 
    List goldLane = List.filled(3, null, growable: false);

  
 
    void _alterLanesOnContractEnds() {
    for (var i in goldLane) {
      print("\n\n I: $i");
      if (i == null ||
          DateTime.parse(i['contractEnds']).isBefore(
            DateTime.now(),
          )) {
        i = null;
        print('Can be removed');
      } else {
        print('Cannot be removed');
      }
    }
    update();
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for-in` loop will not allow you to reassign elements of the `List`.  When you do:

```dart
for (var i in goldLane) {
  // ...
  i = null;
}
```

you are reassigning what the *local* `i` variable refers to, not mutating the `goldLane` `List`.

You instead can iterate with an index:

```dart
void _alterLanesOnContractEnds() {
  for (var i = 0; i < goldLane.length; i += 1) {
    var element = goldLane[i];
    print("\n\n I: $element");
    if (element == null ||
        DateTime.parse(element['contractEnds']).isBefore(
          DateTime.now(),
        )) {
      goldLane[i] = null;
      print('Can be removed');
    } else {
      print('Cannot be removed');
    }
  }
  update();
}
```

Comment: Greetings James, I did solve the problem you can check my solution but I'll go with your solution as it is more concise. Thank You for the assistance. Also I've multiple Lists that needs to be altered as per same condition, how can alter multiple list in the same Loop function?

Comment: @Shakun's If you need to do the same work on multiple objects, that that's begging for the code to be refactored into a separate function.  You could rename `_alterLanesOnContractEnds` to something more general, make it take a `List` as an argument, and use that throughout the function body instead of using `goldLane` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new `List` where unqualified guests are nullified. For example,

```
void _alterLanesOnContractEnds() {
  goldLane = goldLane.map(
    (guest) => guest == null || DateTime.parse(guest['contractEnds']).isBefore(DateTime.now()) ? null: guest
  ).toList(growable: false);
  update();
}
```

You **should not** and cannot modify a list while iterating with its iterator.

Elaborated by Jamesdlin,

> Modifying the elements of a List while iterating is fine. Modifying
> the length of the List while iterating is not, but that won't be a
> problem for a non-growable List.

The bottom line is you should not mutate the size of the list while iterating.

Comment: Greetings, The Fixed List is broken by implying your solution because the List items are removed. If the condition is met, I want to set the value of the list index element to null. @saw

Comment: Modifying the *elements* of a `List` while iterating is fine.  Modifying the *length* of the `List` while iterating is not, but that won't be a problem for a non-growable `List`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks. I will put it in the next edit.

Comment: @Shakun's I updated the answer a little bit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Greetings Saw, I tried your solution it's not working. The List stays same. The above two answers have solved the issue. Thank you for your assistance. @saw

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using

```
goldLane.forEach(
      (element) {
        print('\n\n ELEMENT: $element');
        if (element == null ||
            DateTime.parse(element['contractEnds']).isBefore(
              DateTime.now(),
            )) {
          int ix = goldLane.indexWhere(
            (element) => element != null
                ? DateTime.parse(element['contractEnds']).isBefore(
                    DateTime.now(),
                  )
                : true,
          );
          goldLane[ix] = null;
        } else {
          print('Cannot be removed');
        }
      },
    );
```

Yet I'll test the other answers. Thank You.

Comment: This approach is inefficient (it is O(n^2) instead of O(n)).  In general, you also should prefer regular `for`/`for-in` loops over using `Iterable.forEach`.

Comment: Already implemented your solution. Thanks for the heads up. @jamesdlin